# What is the best way to automatically unite multiple json arrays in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to automatically unite multiple json arrays in a loop? Json arrays are created automatically and have no names.

```
    loop:
      Array [ Object ]
      Array [ Object ]
      Array [ Object ]
```

Comment: Please be more specific - for example, what does the raw data look like?  What is the behavior you're trying to accomplish?  "automatically unite multiple json arrays in a loop" is too vague.  Do you mean that you have a loop that creates x number of JS objects, and you want to put them all into an array?

Comment: Yeah how are they arrays generated? Can you show any of your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method on an array of arrays to get one array containing the contents of the inner arrays.

```
const arrays = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];
const result = arrays.flat();
```

result: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`